# Send LIST from c# to angular

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, data-transfer

I have backend c# api

```
public async Task<Object> GetTestType()
{
        List <TestType> TestList = _context.TestTypes.ToList();
        foreach (var l in TestTypeList)
        {
            Log.WriteLog("log.txt", "test1 > " + l.var1);
        }
        Log.WriteLog("log.txt", "test2 > "+TestList .ToString());
    return TestList ;
}
```

In log I get

> ```
> test1 > testvar1
> test1 > testvar2
> test1 > testvar3
>
> test2 > System.Collections.Generic.List`1[BackEnd.Entities.TestType]
> ```

Here is TestType class

```
public class TestType
{
    public int id{ get; set; }
    public string var1{ get; set; }
    public string var2{ get; set; }
}
```

in angular I have

```
this.TestService.getTestType().subscribe(
  (res:any)=>
  {
    console.log(res) ; 

    this.RideTypeModelData.rideTypeID = res.rideTypeID;
    console.log('rideTypeID-'+this.RideTypeModelData.rideTypeID) ; 
  },
```

In case of **console.log(res)**  I get

> [object Object]

I also created TestModel in angular

```
export class TestTypeModel{
    id: Number;
    typeWebID: String;
    var1: String;
    var2: String;
}
```

And am trying to use it to get object data by this
 public TestTypeModelData: TestTypeModel;

```
this.TestService.getTestType().subscribe(
  (res:any)=>
  {
    this.TestTypeModelData.id= res.id;
    console.log(this.TestTypeModelData.id) ; 
  },
```

And I get error

> core.js:15723 ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of undefined

How can I transfer that List object and output it in angular ???

Comment: this.TestTypeModelData is probably null when you're trying to set his id property. If that's the case you need to create a new TestTypeModel before : this.TestTypeModelData = new TestTypeModel()

Comment: I've updated question with log from api. which shows that api sends data

Comment: try `res[0].id` instead of `res.id`

Comment: doesn't help , same error :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your api is returning a collection like a list of TestType however in your angular code your are tyring to assign this collection to an id.

you should iterate the `res` object and then set the id values.